# cannot run android text to speech

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-to-speech

My code is as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    runBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_run_demo);
    ttobj = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });
    runBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        }
    });
}

public void onPause() {
    if (ttobj != null) {
        ttobj.stop();
        ttobj.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

public void speakText(String text) {
    String toSpeak = text;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

        //do my stuff

        speakText("Hello");

    }
}
```

Although I am able to do my stuff I am not able to run `speech`.

Am I missing something ??

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `onActivityResult()` is called the `TextToSpeech` is already shutdown since you shut it down in `onPause()`. You have to either set a flag to speak "Hello" when `TextToSpeech` is reinitialize or put your code in `onPause()` in `onDestroy()`.